# How to adjust alpha parameter in gensim LdaModel

Tags: python, alpha, gensim, topic-modeling

I have trained an topic model using a symmetric alpha in my lda distibution:

```
model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(bows, num_topics = 20, id2word = dictionary, passes = 100)
```

I can see that:

```
model.alpha
array([ 0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,
    0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,
    0.05,  0.05])
```

where

```
numpy.sum(model.alpha)
1.0000000000000002
```

I can't quite understand how gensim allows for lowering alpha parameter to allow each document to be a mixture of fewer topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking as the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)

It seems like `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel` takes an `alpha` parameter that defaults to `'symmetric'`. You can either explicitly provide it an array of alphas, or set it to `'auto'` and it will learn the priors from your data.

I suggest trying it with `alpha='auto'` to let it learn the priors.

Comment: I think explicitly setting it to an array, like you mentioned, is what I'll do.

Comment: @r2d2oid cool. I would definitely suggest trying out `'auto'`, letting the algorithm learn the asymmetric priors has given me good results in the past!